# Iterating through a list of items with each step awaiting user input before moving on to next item in list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of items that I want to present to the user one-by-one, this being controlled by awaiting user input before showing next item.

To give a contextual example this could be a list of questions that the user has to answer one-by-one. Each question will have question body and a list of options for user to select. They could be presented by a single `Card` to begin with and once they have selected one of the options the value is captured and the next `Card` is displayed below

So the super simplified version off what I have is something like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class QuestionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  QuestionScreen();

  @override
  _QuestionScreenState createState() => _QuestionScreenState();
}

class _QuestionScreenState extends State<QuestionScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Question> listOfQuestions = [
      new Question(),
      new Question(),
      new Question()
    ];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('List Of Questions'),
          ...listOfQuestions.map((eachQuestion) {
            return Card(
              elevation: 10,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 5,
                horizontal: 10,
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(eachQuestion.questionText),
                subtitle: Row(
                  children: [
                    ...eachQuestion.listOfOptionsForTheUserToSelect
                        .map((eachOption) {
                      return ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => {},
                        child: Text(eachOption),
                      );
                    }).toList()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Question {
  String questionText = "question";
  List<String> listOfOptionsForTheUserToSelect = ["ans1", "ans2"];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use two lists. A source list with all the questions, and a second list to display the questions as they are answered.

Here is your code updated with a very basic solution as example.

Note I added in a small boolean check so an already answered question can't be answered twice, and also to stop throwing an error once all questions are completed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class QuestionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  QuestionScreen();

  @override
  _QuestionScreenState createState() => _QuestionScreenState();
}

class _QuestionScreenState extends State<QuestionScreen> {
  List<Question> listOfQuestions = [Question(), Question(), Question()];
  List<Question> listOfQuestionsToDisplay = [];

  int currentIndex = 0;

  initState() {
    listOfQuestionsToDisplay.add(listOfQuestions[0]);
    super.initState();
  }

  onQuestionPress({required int index}) {
    print('index pressed is $index');
    print('current index is $currentIndex');

    if (index < currentIndex) {
      print('already pressed');
    } else if (listOfQuestions.length == listOfQuestionsToDisplay.length) {
      print('all questions answered');
    } else {
      listOfQuestionsToDisplay.add(listOfQuestions[index + 1]);
      currentIndex++;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('List Of Questions'),
          ...listOfQuestionsToDisplay.map((eachQuestion) {
            return Card(
              elevation: 10,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 5,
                horizontal: 10,
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                    '${eachQuestion.questionText} Q/NO: ${listOfQuestionsToDisplay.indexOf(eachQuestion)}'),
                subtitle: Row(
                  children: [
                    ...eachQuestion.listOfOptionsForTheUserToSelect
                        .map((eachOption) {
                      return ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => {
                          onQuestionPress(
                              index: listOfQuestionsToDisplay
                                  .indexOf(eachQuestion)),
                        },
                        child: Text(eachOption),
                      );
                    }).toList()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }).toList()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Question {
  String questionText = "question";
  List<String> listOfOptionsForTheUserToSelect = ["ans1", "ans2"];
}
```